# Change Label for POI on Google Maps API 3

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I tried searching Google Forums and on here, and could not find a solid answer or example on how to achieve what I am looking for.

I currently fill all airports a specific color using the below code

```
var myOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
    scaleControl: true,
    //scrollwheel: false,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU},
                styles: [
                {
                    featureType: "transit.station.airport",
                    elementType: "geometry.fill",
                    stylers: [{ hue: "#cc0000" }, { lightness: -50 }, { saturation: 50 }]
                },
                {
                    featureType: "transit.station.airport",
                    elementType: "labels.text.fill",
                    stylers: [{"color": "#000000"}]
                }

                ]
            };
}
```

I am wondering if there is any way to adjust the size of the icon (tiny airplane) that can only be seen once you zoom in quite a bit. Changing this icon is not 100% required, as the default icon suits my needs just fine, but I am wondering if there is any way to 1) Control the size of the default icon/label or 2) Overlay a custom label for each instance of the airport.

Thanks, in advance, for your help.

Comment: You cannot change the size of the icon with styled maps.

Comment: Ok, any idea a good way to overlay a marker on each transit.station.airport?

Comment: Do a geocode query every time the map is moved for "airport" (e.g. `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=airport&bounds={{northeast: lat,lng}}|{{southwest: lat,lng}}` and put markers on the results that are returned